# fdisk: could not detect sector size of USB hard disk on FreeBSD

Tags: mount, freebsd, usb, fdisk, ntfs-3g

I have an NTFS formatted USB hard disk that works fine (mounts and unmounts cleanly) on my windows desktop.

I can't however seem to mount it on my freebsd box at all.

Stripping this back to the basics, I can confirm the box sees the USB device,

```
pfSense log/ root^> dmesg
ugen1.5: <Seagate> at usbus1
umass1: <Seagate Expansion Desk, class 0/0, rev 2.10/1.00, addr 5> on usbus1
da1 at umass-sim1 bus 1 scbus2 target 0 lun 0
da1: <Seagate Expansion Desk 0604> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-6 device
da1: Serial Number NA4KXT5F
da1: 40.000MB/s transfers
da1: 3815447MB (976754645 4096 byte sectors: 255H 63S/T 60800C)
da1: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
```

The USB device also shows up under camcontrol and usbconfig

```
pfSense log/ root^> usbconfig
ugen0.1: <XHCI root HUB 0x8086> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=SUPER (5.0Gbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen1.1: <EHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen1.2: <product 0x8001 vendor 0x8087> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen1.3: <USB2.0 Hub vendor 0x05e3> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE (100mA)
ugen1.4: <USB Storage Generic> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (500mA)
ugen1.5: <Expansion Desk Seagate> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON (0mA)

pfSense log/ root^> camcontrol devlist
<C400-MTFDDAK256MAM 070H>          at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (ada0,pass0)
<Generic STORAGE DEVICE 9451>      at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass1,da0)
<Seagate Expansion Desk 0604>      at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (da1,pass2)
```

But running a simply command like `fdisk -p` gets me nowhere,

```
pfSense log/ root^> fdisk -p /dev/da1
fdisk: could not detect sector size
```

Any pointers on where I am going wrong would be very helpful.

PS, in case anyone picked up on it from the hostname, this is a box running pfsense with Finch for various jails.  The ntfs-3g and all the troubleshooting is under finch.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

Not sure this did the trick, but here were the steps,

```
diskinfo -c da1

mount_ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/da1s1 /media/multi-media/
fuse: failed to open fuse device: No such file or directory

vi /etc/rc.conf
# add the following line to the end
# fusefs_enable="YES"
kldload fuse.ko

mount_ntfs-3g -o windows_names,inherit /dev/da1s1 /usr/jails/sharedfs/media/
# finally works without errors
```

Wonder if using diskinfo got the rest of BSD to recognise that the hard disk has a non standard sector size?

Answer (score 0):

Install NTFS-3G

```
pkg install ntfs-3g
```

Load the fuse driver:

```
modprobe fuse
```

Create a mount point, enter:

```
 mkdir /mnt/ntfs
```

To mount the ntfs partition:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdX /mnt/ntfs
```

Comment: I would have thought fdisk being able to read the sector size is completely unrelated to whether ntfs is installed.  Having said that, I had already installed it.  `pfSense // root^> pkg info fusefs-ntfs-2015.3.14_3
fusefs-ntfs-2015.3.14_3
Name           : fusefs-ntfs`